# I just reset my android phone, how do I recover my Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: factory-reset, 5.1-lollipop, data-recovery, chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I just reset my Moto G, hoping that the Chrome bookmarks would be synced to my account but they haven't and I lost them all. They were extremely valuable and I want all of them back. Please let me know any methods to recover them! I am willing to root my phone for this!

Comment: It's impossible unless you synchronized them (what you haven't done).

Answer (score 0):

Just login to your Google account and all data will be automatically imported includng your history, bookmarks, extensions etc.